# How do I extend an existing entity?

Tags: 8, entities

I would like to add some custom fields to the taxonomy_term_data table.

How do I programmatically extend the *Term* entity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a hook for that `hook_entity_base_field_info()`. The code could look something like this

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_base_field_info().
 */
function module_name_entity_base_field_info(\Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() === 'taxonomy_term') {
    $fields['new_field'] = \Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition::create('string')
      ->setLabel(t('Label'));

    // You can add more options about visibility configuration etc.

    return $fields;
  }
}
```

The above could add "hidden" field, (not visible in display or edit mode and not configurable). You need to do the same thing as when creating base fields in a custom entity.